# .Net 6.0: "AesManaged" является устаревшим: 'Derived cryptographic types are obsolete. Use the Create method on the base type instead.'

Tags: .net, .net-6

Уважаемые участники сообщества!

Помогите улучшить код! Для шифрования строк (нужно для сохранения конфиденциальных данных в общую базу данных) использую класс:

```
public static class StringEncriptor
    {
        private static readonly byte[] KEY = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

        public static string Encrypt (string text)
        {
            using AesManaged aes = new() { Key = KEY };
            using MemoryStream ms = new();
            ms.Write(aes.IV);
            using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
            {
                cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }

        public static string Decrypt (string base64)
        {
            using MemoryStream ms = new(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            ms.Read(iv);
            using AesManaged aes = new() { Key = KEY, IV = iv };
            using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
            using MemoryStream output = new();
            cs.CopyTo(output);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Он нормально отрабатывал и полностью выполнял свои функции в .Net 5.0. С релизом .Net 6.0 решил перейти на него (проект ещё в ранней стадии, поэтому вполне реально). И вот столкнулся с таким предупреждением:

```
SYSLIB0021  "AesManaged" является устаревшим: 'Derived cryptographic types are obsolete. Use the Create method on the base type instead.'
```

Понятное дело, что надо использовать метод Create родителя. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться...

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_Aes_Create

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Можно пример использования?

Comment: `using Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");` Все что поменялось.

Comment: А как же тогда задаётся параметр KEY? И вообще, как задать ключ?

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите то на класс `Aes`: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0#properties видите там свойство ключа и вектора? Вот туда и устанавливайте ключ и вектор. `aes.Key = ...;` `aes.IV = ...`.

Comment: `new() { Key = KEY, IV = iv };` это не параметры конструктора, а всего-лишь синтаксический сахар языка. Так всего лишь устанавливаются значения свойств так как я показал это выше, ничего больше.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Что-то меня заглючило...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо большое пользователю @Kotomi за ответ. Он предложил правильный вариант, которым я делюсь:

```
public static class StringEncriptor
{
    private static readonly byte[] KEY = Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

    public static string Encrypt (string text)
    {
        using Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
        aes.Key = KEY;
        using MemoryStream ms = new();
        ms.Write(aes.IV);
        using (CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true))
        {
            cs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    public static string Decrypt (string base64)
    {
        using MemoryStream ms = new(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        ms.Read(iv);
        using Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");
        aes.Key = KEY;
        aes.IV = iv;
        using CryptoStream cs = new(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
        using MemoryStream output = new();
        cs.CopyTo(output);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }
}
```